# How can I reappear in Google search result?

Tags: redirects, penalty

My website recently got a manual action penalty by Google due to "Sneaky mobile redirects" and not appearing on Google search results. This is what they said;

"Google has detected sneaky redirects for mobile users on your site. This means that mobile users visiting your site are redirected to another page or are shown different content than your desktop users. This creates an unexpected experience for Google Search users and violates our Webmaster Guidelines. Therefore Google has prevented the offending pages from showing in search results. This manual spam action has been applied to example.com/ . To reinstate these pages in search results, remove the spam and file a reconsideration request. After we determine that you have complied with our guidelines, we will remove this manual action".

Moreover, we did a redirection of a sub domain (bengali.example.com to examplw.com) some times back by 301 permanent redirect using htaccess

However, we have disabled all redirection happening on a mobile device and filed a reconsideration request but it was rejected again. We can't detect any issues that is redirecting users on a mobile device now. Therefore, please suggest what we should do to revoke manual penalty action imposed by Google

Comment: Sorry but the question is far too board... the only information you provided is Google say this, you say this. We need more information on the redirect you were using previously and how you removed it, how long you waited and sharing the site in question would be helpful.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks for your reply. The site in question is (http://kolkata24x7.com) . Earlier, there was some redirect issues on the site where upon loading on mobile device the site was redirected to Google play ads which ask users to install apps. We disabled that and now there is no such redirection happening both in the desktop and mobile version of the site. Still Google rejected our reconsideration request stating the same thing "sneaky mobile redirect". Moreover, we did a redirection of a subdomain (bengali.kolkata24x7.com to kolkata24x7.com) some times back. Is that OK?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the additional information, including 'HOW' you were redirecting (htaccess, javascript, user agent and so on). Include all relevant snippets of the message Google team sent you in.

Comment: @SimonHayter I have shared the detail as per your suggestion